# how to modify ordered (non template ) fact, say the nth value?

Tags: clips

modify is not working. I expected fact 1 to be **(a x y z)**.

Further, if I want to change the second element **c** of the fact 1 to say **g**, i.e the new fact should be `(a b g d)` is there a way using modify ? 
Snippet attached below.

```
CLIPS> (assert (a b c d))

<Fact-1>

CLIPS> (bind ?s x y z)

(x y z)

CLIPS> (facts)

f-1     (a b c d)

For a total of 1 fact.

CLIPS> ?s

(x y z)

CLIPS> (modify 1 (implied ?s))

FALSE

CLIPS> (facts)

f-1     (a b c d)

For a total of 1 fact.

CLIPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify only works with template facts. If you're using ordered facts, you need to do a retract and assert:

```
CLIPS> (assert (a b c d))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (bind ?s x y z)
(x y z)
CLIPS> (retract 1)
CLIPS> (assert (a ?s))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-2     (a x y z)
For a total of 1 fact.
CLIPS>
```

Use the replace$ function to replace values in a multifield value before asserting it as part of a fact:

```
CLIPS> (bind ?s (replace$ ?s 2 2 g))
(x g z)
CLIPS>
```